# Oracle count my data used

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Say I have a table like this

```sql
ID, SN, USED

002, 183000153206, 0
002, 180000205206, 0
002, 188000373206, 0
002, 186000495206, 0
002, 181000521206, 0

001, 180000107106, 0
001, 181000206106, 0
001, 182000337106, 0
001, 180000453106, 1
001, 188000557106, 0
001, 184000639106, 0
```

I would like to count SN used count for each ID, if my SQL script is right, the result could be :

```sql
ID, USED_Count
002, 0
001, 1
```

Here's what I did so far, but it only shows ID 001 record, no ID 002.

```sql
select   id, count(sn) as sums
from     sn_table
where    sn is not null
and      used is not null
group by id
--having   sums >= 0
```

I know the condition *used is not null* seems not right, but I just stocked here for hours, how can I done this ?

Comment: Your query returns rows for both `001` and `002` for the posted sample data. Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/823bd/1). If you want us to help you need to provide a test case which actually demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use simple `SUM`:

```
select   id, SUM(used) as sums
from     sn_table
group by id
order by id desc;
```

or conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN used = 1 THEN sn END) AS USED_COUNT
FROM sn_table
GROUP BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34a78a24b6e0cb3088e249eed3951569)**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what logic you're trying to implement. maybe you just want to count distinct occurrences of each column?

```
select   id
         , count(distinct sn) as sn_cnt
         , count(distinct used) as used_cnt
from     sn_table
where    sn is not null
and      used is not null
group by id
```